# "Sofa bed", "hideaway couch", "hide-a-bed", "couch bed", "sleeper sofa", "day bed", and "studio couch" in AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

Which of these terms is (or are) more typical of AE to designate a convertible consisting of an upholstered couch that can be converted into a double bed?

Comment: A day bed is not a couch. It is a bed.

Comment: Is anyone else getting the sense that Nourished has been sent here from another planet to study us?

Comment: @Oldcat http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/30080316/

Comment: NG, that piece of Ikea furniture is not a couch, it is a bed.

Comment: A convertible is a kind of car (in AmE). A sofa bed, a sleeper sofa. I haven't heard of the other terms before (except for day bed).

Comment: @Mitch I know that, Mitch. The thing is "studio couch" is defined as such im the FOD http://www.thefreedictionary.com/studio+couch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhetorician makes me believe the answer to be dialectal in nature. Whereas he's from upstate New York, I'm from the New York City area.

For us, *sleeper-sofa* or *sofa-bed* are the most common usage. We never use *hide-a-bed*.

A large maker of sleeper-sofas calls them convertible sofas. The name of the company is Jennifer Convertibles.

A *day-bed* is different.  This is a deeper couch, the depth of a twin bed, which has pillows on it to make it usable as a couch by day and bed by night.

I've not seen *studio couch* or *couch bed* used in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Where I hail from, it's got to be hide-a-bed or sofa-bed (not on your list). I grew up in upstate New York, by the way, near the Great Lake of Ontario. Hide-a-beds are put to good use by couch potatoes; they can sit or lie down in comfort and at the same time be glued to the TV both day and night!

***ADDENDUM***

In my haste, I forgot that "we" sometimes appended the word *sofa* to hide-a-bed, as in *hide-a-bed sofa*.

Also, where I grew up, the only brand name for a sofa-bed was a *Castro Convertible*, with no *sofa*, *couch*, *hide-a-bed*, or *sleeper-sofa* appended.